# how to solve this error? Ques:check array is sorted or not

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

```
class Solution:
    def arraySortedOrNot(self, arr, n):
        # code here
        if n==0 or n==1:
            return True
        if arr[0]>arr[1]:
            return False
        else:
            ans=self.arraySortedOrNot(arr[1:],n-1)
            return bool(ans)

**ERROR**
156 /265
For Input: 
3565
3 7 12 14 16 20 20 25 28 33 37 38 40 43 45 48 50 54 57 59 59 62 64 64 66 69 69 70 74 79 83 86 88 91 94 98 100 101 106 106 110 113 114 119 119 124 127 128 132 135 136 139 139 141 141 141 143 143 1.................
 Input is too large Download Full File 
Your Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/2d2bd66b81191dd0e80b01c4f1b32f41.py", line 28, in <module>
    ans = ob.arraySortedOrNot(arr, n)
  File "/home/2d2bd66b81191dd0e80b01c4f1b32f41.py", line 11, in arraySortedOrNot
    ans=self.arraySortedOrNot(arr[1:],n-1)
  File "/home/2d2bd66b81191dd0e80b01c4f1b32f41.py", line 11, in arraySortedOrNot
    ans=self.arraySortedOrNot(arr[1:],n-1)
  File "/home/2d2bd66b81191dd0e80b01c4f1b32f41.py", line 11, in arraySortedOrNot
    ans=self.arraySortedO.................
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to iterate through the elements of the array and return `False` if you reach an element that is smaller than the previous one otherwise return `True`.

for example:

```
if n==0 or n==1:
    return True
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i-1] > arr[i]:
        return False
return True
```